# custom user auth in django how to hook up

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, authorization, jwt

So the django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/ are great but I am confused, it would be great to have a mentor right now.

I want to create a custom user model and authentication system

```
the user model will have 
-name
-password
-email
-JWT (javascript web token)
```

a permissions and a venue (place of entertainment) will be connected to this user model via a many to many relation via an association table.

Here is the problem, even with the docs I am confused how I override the current out of box implementation for authorization.

Additionally I'd like to use https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt

for the token auth but I have no idea how to hook it up. I guess I am looking for a walk through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove fields from the built in User, you should use this model:

```
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=75, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, numbers and '
                    'underscores characters'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(re.compile('^[\w]+$'), 
            _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=254, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length = 254, unique = True, null = True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
```

This allows you to customise your User model fully. You can remove the appropriate fields. Then follow the instructions for setting up djangorestframework-jwt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, django has built-in User,for convenience you can use it, if you need to add other fields to current django User model:

```
form django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(User):
    # define your additional custom fields
```

after installing djangorestframework-jwt do this setting in your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        ...
    ),
}

JWT_AUTH = {
    # JWT related settings, see the docs
}
```

In urls.py just add this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    ...
]
```

Now you should first browse for getting a token and then browse your other APIs:

Do a post request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/ and provide username and password to obtain your token.
On other requests, you should send this token:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/yoururl
HEADER
Authorization JWT <YourToken>
```

You can go forward with your requests with curl, httpie, postman (chrome app) or any other HttpClient

Comment: great thank you. Now, regarding the many to many. I imagine I just create that Using djangos ORM ( I am familar with many to many implementation) for the venues and permissions models... I could use djangos contenttypes but thats another can of worms I'd rather stay away from @Serjik